# Why is validation not run within second form?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

A (Richfaces) popup with an own form provides a save button which must execute another form (`contentForm`) and do not forward if validation failures occurs.

However, `saveHandler.forward()` is always invoked... any ideas?

```
<a4j:commandButton 
    id="saveContentChanges" 
    value="Speichern" 
    action="#{cc.attrs.handler.save()}"
    type="submit"> 
    <a4j:ajax 
        execute=":contentForm" 
        render=":contentForm"
        oncomplete="if (#{!facesContext.validationFailed}) { saveHandler.forward() } else { #{rich:component('contentSaveHandlerPopup')}.hide() }"
        onerror="errorHandler.onError(event.description); #{rich:component('contentSaveHandlerPopup')}.hide();" />
</a4j:commandButton>
```

PS. This code is within a composite component. I do not get any errors on the JavaScript console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML only single form can be submitted, so in your case only the data from the form where `a4j:commanButton` resides is submitted from client to server. `execute` attribute impacts only server side processing, it does not change how data is submitted. So adding to `execute` a different form makes it actually processed on server side, but since there are no submitted values it means there is nothing to validate.

Alternative solutions are:

1. (preferred) Put popup with the button to the same form which needs to be submitted and validated.
2. Put a a4j:jsFunction to contentForm and call it from popup, code would look like this:

.

```
<h:form id="contentForm">
  .. other fields to be submitted ..
  <a4j:jsFunction name="executeContentFormAction" execute="@form" render="@form"
        action="#{...}"
        oncomplete="if ..."/>
</h:form>

...

<a4j:commandButton 
    id="saveContentChanges" 
    value="Speichern"
    onclick="executeContentFormAction(); return false;">
```

Comment: Thank you Andrey! In addition, I had to hide the popup with `onbeforesubmit` otherwise it was not working too. But now it's working perfect.